# Write if else logic before creating api in serializer DRF

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, logic, django-serializer

I need to write if else logic to show text alongside my values.before using get method.

**models.py**

```
class AnalysisResult(models.Model):
    user_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    E=models.IntegerField()
    A=models.IntegerField()
    C=models.IntegerField()
    N=models.IntegerField()
    O=models.IntegerField()
    total=models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table='analysis_result'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.response
```

using DRF and serializer I have created api for this model.my created api looks like this when i hit url .

```
[
    {
        "user_id": 1,
        "E": 25,
        "A": 14,
        "C": 14,
        "N": 38,
        "O": 8,
        "total": 99
    }
]
```

but now i want to show some text based on the value of individual E,A,C,N,O. my api should look something like this

```
[
    {
        "user_id": 1,
        "E": 25,
        "A": 14,
        "C": 14,
        "N": 38,
        "O": 8,
        "total": 99,
        "E_Text":"some text",
        "A_Text":"some text",
        "C_Text":"some text",
        "N_text":"some text",
        "O_text":"some text",
         
    }
]
```

this texts vary with different values of E,A,C,N,O

how can i achieve this task i am not understanding.Please give me a lead.

**serailizer.py**

```
class AnalysisResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model=AnalysisResult
        fields='__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def AnalysisResultInfo(request,user_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        Results=AnalysisResult.objects.filter(pk=user_id)
        serializer=AnalysisResultSerializer(Results, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('Results/<int:user_id>/',views.AnalysisResultInfo)
```

I dont want to store all these texts in database . i have an idea in mind this can be done using **SerializerMethodField()**. i just dont know how .

Comment: The response you want to get is not a valid JSON.

Comment: oh okay ! i get it i have edited now but still my question remains same .

Comment: @Ajaysaini also if u can suggest me an appropriate title for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SerializerMethodField

```
class AnalysisResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    E_Text = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    A_Text = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    C_Text = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    N_Text = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    O_Text = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta:
        model=AnalysisResult
        fields='__all__'
    
    def get_E_Text(self, obj):
        # get your in obj and do the math
        return "String you wanted"

    # Do same for all other fields
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SerializerMethodField()` like this

```
class AnalysisResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    E_Text = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model=AnalysisResult
        fields='__all__'
    
    def get_E_Text(self, obj):
        # derive the result from obj instance
        return result
```

Or you can add property decorator to model like this

```
class AnalysisResult(models.Model):
    user_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    E=models.IntegerField()
    A=models.IntegerField()
    C=models.IntegerField()
    N=models.IntegerField()
    O=models.IntegerField()
    total=models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table='analysis_result'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.response

    @property
    def E_Text(self):
        # derive the value here
        return result
```

and in serializer

```
class AnalysisResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    E_Text = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model=AnalysisResult
        fields='__all__'
```

difference here is `@propery` field will be available with instance any where in code and `SerializerMethodField` will available at serializer only.

so use any approach according to your use case.